# Nullable reference types: no warning in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, resharper, visual-studio-2022

I am using .NET Core with its "new" features like nullable reference types. Why don't I get a Visual Studio warning (VS 2022, Version 17.6.5) for comparing a non-null string with `null` here:

```
public static void Main()
{
    if (GetNeverNullString() == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Why there is no warning?");
    }
}

static string GetNeverNullString()
{
    return "foo";
}
```

This is never true so unreachable code and probably a bug.

[image: No warning in Visual Studio UI]

If I use Resharper I get a warning, but it will be "hidden" in Extensions > Resharper > Inspect > Code issues in solution.

[image: Resharper warning]

Is it possible to get a Visual Studio warning in the [error list window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/error-list-window?view=vs-2022) if I use non-nullable variables and methods as if they could be/return `null`?

Comment: I think you answered your own question: Use ReSharper.

Comment: @madreflection: well, it's not causing a visual studio warning, so it's "hidden" if you don't look at this code. If you want to ensure that all developers solve warnings before they commit, it doesn't help if there are still some hidden issues like this. Many of the resharper warnings can be ignored but this one might be a serious bug, so i want to ensure that we see it. Some developers also don't use resharper, so they don't notice it either.

Comment: I don't use ReSharper, so I'll take your word for it. But no, the base C# compiler will not produce this warning.

Answer (score 2):

Nullable reference types, contrary to nullable value types, are purely a syntactical feature. (They're just annotations.) So, they can technically always still be null, and checking for null is completely valid (especially when migrating legacy code.)

Checking for null is never a bad idea (basing your entire logic on "if something is null or not" might be, though), and it's not really a likely case to be a bug, even when comparing to something that's not annotated as nullable. With that argumentation, *any* if statement might technically be wrong, basically. The opposite case, *not* checking for null, is always way more dangerous.

In fact, if you do check a variable against null, which is annotated as non-null, the compiler will assume that you know something that it doesn't, and treat the variable as nullable from then on. So you might get some warnings in the following code after all (or suggestions, at least, depending on your configuration).

I guess getting a warning anyways wouldn't be the worst idea, and I don't even know if VS supports this (and it's not the point of my answer). I just felt I should point this out. More warnings is not always better, you may end up having so many you stop caring, or explicitly ignoring most of them, which is gonna make a mess.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, they can technically always still be `null`. But if that wouldn't be true we would even get a compiler error and my question was redundant. The actual code was indeed a bug in a public web-api which would have been noticed if visual studio would show a hint or warning (or if the developer would use resharper). If a code branch depends on if something is null the logic is broken which might even be worse than a `NullReferenceException` because you don't notice it. If it was possible to configure it as warning, you can always disable it if you don't want it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I see your point and hopefully that was clear from my answer. My point was, code _depending_ on something being null is rarely a good design choice. Usually it should be more of a fallback, not break anything. That's why I think 9/10 times null checks on non-null are legit, and therefore warning every time probably not reasonable. Unit tests would be the way to go.

Comment: I disagree that "depending on something being null is rarely a good design choice". You have explained it yourself. That part of code is executed if there was no result, so you can call it a fallback. But this fallback could also be the normal case(there is no rule that being able to resolve something should be the default case). My point is that this code is never triggered, so it's a silent bug.

Comment: In my case the bug was that the method did not return null(because the return type was not nullable).  So the null check was correct but the method not. If visual studio showed the warning it was obvious and could have been fixed before going live.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Not to "depend" means, your code ideally should not break, just because something is _not_ null. In your case, it was clearly not _just_ a fallback that was never triggered, which would have been a non-issue. Point is, _every_ if could be wrong, e.g. checking for `< 0` instead of `> 0`, and there is no way a compiler can warn you about _all_ programmer mistakes. That's why you unit test. Short answer: To my knowledge, VS doesn't have a warning for this, and I was just trying to explain why I think that is.